# Как переименовать файл?

Tags: delphi, файлы

Какой функцией или методом можно переименовать файл? Например, файл называется `1.jpg`, надо переименовать его в `2.jpg`.

Comment: Для начала дайте правило переименования файлов и лучше с примером!

Comment: К примеру файл 1.txt - во что его переименовать? А файл 2.txt?

Comment: Все сам сделал , спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 3):

Есть функция:

```
RenameFile('Начальное_имя','Конечное_имя')
```

Воспринимает как полные имена файлов (`C:/1/1.txt`), так и относительные (`1.txt`). Цикл можно запустить по строкам Memo.